# When I get a "filesystem is full" error, but "df" shows there is free space, what the problem can be?

Tags: linux

When I `touch` a file, like `touch test.txt`, I got a message which showed **no space left on device**.

> touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': no space left on device

But when I `df`, it shows Available is more than 10GB.
What's gone wrong?

Comment: do you have multiple partitions? are you sure you create the file on the one that has space left?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check if you see zero IFree.
`df -i` should help with this:

```
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev            60107   322  59785    1% /dev
```

If you see enough free inodes - take a look if you have deleted but still opened file(s). Something like this:

```
lsof -nP | grep '(deleted)'

tail      18687           root    3r      REG                8,1        0     130833 /root/test (deleted)
```

Comment: IMHO, if still opened, it should not appear in df

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.